# Can I use a switch statement to transform each value in an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, switch-statement

I want to transform the contents of an array based on where each value falls in a range.  The range criteria seem like something that would be easiest to represent in a switch statement, but I am having trouble putting it together or locating a similar example online.

I'm a beginner so please forgive any obvious stupidity, but here is an example of something I tried that should be illustrative:

```
    var times = [3,12,4,9,17,22]

    var timeAdjustments: [Int] {
     for i in times {
      switch i {
       case 20...: 50
       case 15...: 70
       case 10...: 80
       case 5...: 90
       case 0...: 100
       default: print("out of range")
    }
    timeAdjustments.append(i)
}
```

In this example, the goal would be to return an array like this : [100,80,100,90,70,50].

Comment: And the range is zero to infinity?

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is just to `(compact)Map` the array

```
let times = [3,12,4,9,17,22]

let timeAdjustments = times.compactMap { item -> Int? in
    switch item {
        case 20...: return 50
        case 15...: return 70
        case 10...: return 80
        case 5...: return 90
        case 0...: return 100
        default : print("\(item) is out of range"); return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The ranges are correct, but the you're not actually doing anything with each case.
You need to append not `i` to `timeAdjustment`, but the value resulting in each case. So, you'd probably want to assign it to some temporary variable, and then append that instead of `i`.

```
var timeAdjustments: [Int] = []

for i in times {
    var j: Int? = nil
    switch i {
    case 20...: j = 50
    case 15...: j = 70
    case 10...: j = 80
    case 5...: j = 90
    case 0...: j = 100
    default: print("out of range")
    }
    if let j = j { timeAdjustments.append(j) }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would work, but using map (or `compactMap`, as in vadian's answer) seems cleaner and more "Swifty".

Comment: @DuncanC, sure, but I was optimizing for understandability, as it seems the OP is fairly new to Swift, so I stayed closed to his code so that he could see the differences.

Comment: Fair point. If you wanted to take it to the next level, you could add a second part to your answer that said "now, there is a function in Swift called compactMap..." and then show the equivalent using that as a second option.

Answer (score 0):

## Please try the below mention solution:

```
var times = [3, 12, 4, 9, 17, 22]

var timeAdjustments: [Int] = []

for i in times {
    var adjustment: Int // Variable to store the adjustment
    
    switch i {
    case 20...:
        adjustment = 50
    case 15...:
        adjustment = 70
    case 10...:
        adjustment = 80
    case 5...:
        adjustment = 90
    case 0...:
        adjustment = 100
    default:
        print("out of range")
        adjustment = 0 // Default adjustment if it's out of all specified ranges
    }
    
    timeAdjustments.append(adjustment) // Append the adjusted value to the array
}

print(timeAdjustments) // [100, 80, 100, 90, 70, 50]
```